# insert accented characters in Google Worksheet?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, gdata-api, google-sheets-api

I am inserting Data into a Google Worksheet using :

```
var row = new RowWork(null, null, {
    column1: col1,
    column2: col2,
});

this.GData.postEntry(row);
```

and

```
toAtom: function() {
return '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">'+
            '<gsx:col1><![CDATA['+this.col1+']]></gsx:col1>'+
            '<gsx:col2><![CDATA['+this.col2+']]></gsx:col2>'+
        '</entry>';
}

postEntry: function(row)
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var atom = row.toAtom();

    req.open('POST', row.editurl, false);
    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'GoogleLogin auth='+ClientLogin.token);
    req.setRequestHeader('GData-Version', '3.0');
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8');
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', atom.length);
    req.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
    req.sendAsBinary(atom);

    if(! req.responseText.match(/^<\?xml.+/)) {
        throw new Error(req.responseText);
    }

    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var DOM = parser.parseFromString(req.responseText, "text/xml");
    row.editurl = DOM.getElementsByTagName('link')[1].getAttribute('href');
    row.etag = DOM.getElementsByTagName('entry')[0].getAttribute('gd:etag');

    return row;
},
```

But the data i am inserting sometimes have accented character, so once inserted let say for example : `mécho` I get `m�cho` in the worksheet. And when using `alert(col2)` before the insertion, i get the right `mécho`.

what seems to be the problem?

Comment: are you using google-apps-script. Do you have the right question tags?

Comment: I am using the Google API

Comment: "Google API"?  .... Are you using: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/ or https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Comment: I am a little confused with the names, it is Gdata ...

Comment: I tried it with the Java GData 3,0 API (google-spreadsheet-api). And all works fine, both read and write. I encoded with java using \u00E9 So no idea why you get a problem, as I think they both use the same protocol. ... my guess would be, it does work, if you can get the encoding right.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will dig more and see if i can come up with something :D

Answer (score 1):

Use the `replace` function to convert the literal to its XML entity equivalent:

```
var atom = row.toAtom().replace(/é/g, "&#233;");
```

**References**

- [ISO Latin-1 Character Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537495)